# How to set the color of the input bar in LibreOffice Calc spreadsheets (for dark theme/mode)?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, themes, openoffice-calc, dark-mode

In LibreOffice Calc, I have been able to almost configure a usable dark theme/mode.

To accomplish this, go to Tools > Options... > LibreOffice > Personalization and set the dark theme, and then go to Tools > Options... > LibreOffice > Application Colors to set the document background color.

But I am having difficulties making the input bar usable when everything is set to a dark mode.  The issue is that the input bar buttons become almost impossible to see.

I can select a different icon set included with LibreOffice, but none of the others are much better for the input bar, and they are all worse for the main toolbar (when using a dark theme).

Here is an example of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Calc with a dark theme showing buttons in input bar nearly impossible to see]

Is there any way, within LibreOffice, to fix this issue?

Comment: It would be easier to reproduce if you would tell about the modification required to "configure a usable dark theme/mode".

Comment: @tohuwawohu In LO Calc, go to Tools > Options... > LibreOffice > Personalization and set the dark theme, and then go to Tools > Options... > LibreOffice > Application Colors to set the document background color.

Comment: I followed those steps, but the dark theme setting only applied to the toolbars, not to the buttons next to the input bar. Could you please add information about LO version and OS?